# How to use the CellEditor in Java swing

Tags: java, swing, tablecelleditor

I will to create `JList` of `JPanel` , the `JPanel` Peristaltic a  `Jtextfield` and `JLabel` , I'm creating a list of this jpanel

```
public class CasofTablecase extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form CasofTablecase
     */
    public CasofTablecase() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to                       


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I'm adding a `DefaultListCellRenderer`  for my class ( class of `Jlist` )  :

```
   public class dlcr extends DefaultListCellRenderer{

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            return (new CasofTablecase());
        }



    }
```

my problem is , if i click on a `Jtextfield` for To write something , but Something does not happen , how to uses the `CellEditor` .

Comment: A JList doesn't support editing. You should be using a JTable. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796471/how-to-change-description-image-in-jlist-java

Comment: And if you really want to know why we recommend using a `JTable`, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796471/how-to-change-description-image-in-jlist-java/23797943#23797943)