# JAVA GUI - How to make a custom JList entry that has two components, and identify which component was clicked

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I am trying to create a JList of JCheckBoxes. To do this, i created a JListRenderer which will render each individual entry as a checkbox.

```
private class JListRenderer extends JCheckBox implements ListCellRenderer<ACustomClass> {
    
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends ACustomClass> list, ACustomClass value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            //code
            return this;
        }
}
```

I also created a custom ListSelectionListener that will handle the selection of these checkboxes and will select and unselect the checkbox.

```
public class CheckBoxListSelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {
    
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
       //list selection code where i handle how to check or uncheck the JCheckBox
    }
}
```

This is all working really well, hence i have not written body of the code in the above example.

I want the selection of the checkbox part of the entry, separate from the text.
[image: CheckboxImage]

Such that i can select/highlight the text without checking the checkbox. By doing this, I am hoping to choose a single entry and display its values at a different place, while the state of the checkbox stays unchanged.

I tried to create a RowPanel, and replaced JCheckbox with it, such that JList is rendered with RowPanel entries, making the JListRenderer something like this

```
private class JListRenderer extends RowPanel implements ListCellRenderer<RowPanel> {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends RowPanel> list, RowPanel value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            //code
            return this;
        }
}
```

```
public class RowPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

private DataClass data;
private JCheckBox checkbox;
private JLabel label;

/**
 * Creates new form RowPanel
 */
public RowPanel() {
    initComponents();
}

public RowPanel(DataClass value) {
    this.data = value;
    initComponents();
}
}
```

The problem with this approach is, that the ListSelectionListener only identify RowPanel as the source of 'selection' event. How can I identify "**whether the checkbox was selected or the label**"?

Comment: The thing about cell renders is, they aren't "live" components, they are just "snapshots" painted by the parent component, so having them "interact" with the user is actually rather difficult.  My first thought would be to consider using a `JTable` instead

Comment: If you're brave, have time and don't mind tinkering, you could have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796471/how-to-change-description-image-in-jlist-java/23797943#23797943) - but I still think a `JTable` would be easier

Comment: Thanks for this example but at this point, i also feel like JTable would be easier :)

Comment: I used JTable, but JTable uses a ListSelectionModel. My requirements are to choose each cell in a row independently. The JTable has only two columns. I want one column to be a Singe Selection while the other column to be multiple interval selection. Is there any way to do this with JTable, or does using two JList make sense?

Comment: No, I don't think there's a (simple) way to achieve that