# Automate placing a jTextField next to an ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, ocr

I'd like to automate putting a jTextField next to an ImageIcon on the same row basically, for as many rows as I'd like.

I need to do this process depending on how many images I provided as input that's why a manual solution doesn't work for me.

This is an example of what I'd like it to look like. As you can see, an image with a text field next to it for as many rows as I need:

[image: This is an example]

i am working with Java Swing

here is what i tried now in this exemple :

```
public class ImageTextModel {

        private final List<ImageText> images;

        public ImageTextModel() {
            this.images = new ArrayList<>();

            // This is where you would read the OCR images and OCR text from your
            // file system and add the information to the List. I generated OCR images to
            // make the GUI look more realistic.
            /*  
            String name = "John Smith";
            images.add(new ImageText(createBufferedImage(name), name));
            name = "George Washington";
            images.add(new ImageText(createBufferedImage(name), name));
            name = "John Adams";
            images.add(new ImageText(createBufferedImage(name), name));
            name = "Thomas Jefferson";
            images.add(new ImageText(createBufferedImage(name), name));
             */
            String path = "C:\\Users\\ibrahim\\Desktop\\MARKS";
            File folder = new File(path);
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("check path" + listOfFiles[i]);
                String name = listOfFiles[i].toString();
                // load only png
                if (name.endsWith("png")) {
                    images.add(new ImageText(createBufferedImage(name), name));
                }

            }       }
```

and this is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5OLu.png)  it shows me path of image not the image

Comment: It’s difficult to answer you, since you haven’t provided any code.  What is stopping you from doing this now?  Have you ever written a Swing program before?  Have you ever used a [layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/) before? Do you know where the image for each text field will come from?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: I'm not understanding the problem. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. You can easily create a JPanel for the image and text text field. Then add the panel to a parent panel.

Comment: i want a list of image cretaed automaticly from folder contains image  and in front of that list i want an other list of textfield that created depending on the other list

Comment: *"i want a list of image cretaed automaticly from folder contains image"* sounds like you want a `JList` or `JTable`, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796471/how-to-change-description-image-in-jlist-java/23797943#23797943)

Comment: I agree with @MadProgrammer re `JList` / `JTable`, but what is the significance of the text field (presumably editable?) as opposed to a `JLabel` (not editable)?

Comment: i am working with OCR  project of machine learning , i need that my software add automaticly names from folder in a list of image icon and in front of that list i want an other list of jtext fields that contains predicted names from folder ,  they are jtext fields because this is the easy way that i can change in case of wrong result , thanks

Comment: Create ImageText, a plain Java getter / setter class that holds one OCR image and one predicted name String.  Create a List of ImageText instances from the file system folder.  Using the List, create a JTable holding the predicted name String, the OCR image, and a submit JButton.  Put the JTable inside of a JScrollPane, and put the JScrollPane in the center of a JPanel with a BorderLayout.  When you correct a predicted name, left-click the submit JButton and update the predicted name String inside the List of ImageText instances.  When you close the app, write the List to the folder.

Comment: anyone can help me ? with code ?

Comment: realy need help  !?

Comment: @GilbertLEBlanc do u have any code exemple please ?

Comment: @gilbertleblanc  now i want to load Images  from my folder and set it in image icon , here is what i just try ( i edit my question to make u see what i had try ) can u help me so i can load image from my folder

Comment: You use ImageIO to read an image from a file path.  Where's the OCR text located?

Comment: @gilbertleblanc i have probleme , i didnt understand u so much ,, i just send u mail ,, in Colum OCR Image i want to load images that conatins names  from folder , and in Colum OCR text i want also to load names from file.txt and set  it in Jtext field ( i mean i want  the coloum OCR Text would be a text field that loades names from file.txt and i can also correct the names so that i dont need a colum names Corrected text ) is all clear now?

Comment: Your explanation is not even close to clear.  I already wrote your GUI.  You need to learn how to use Java.  Use your favorite search engine to look up "java read text file examples" and "java read image examples".  Neither I nor anyone else can hold your hand and show you step by step how to code a Java Swing application.  Good luck.

Comment: @gilbertLeblanc yes ur right  , thanks gillbert , i appreciate ur help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Introduction

Here's the GUI I came up with.

[image: ImageText GUI]

To use this GUI, you would select the first row that you want to correct with the mouse, and type the corrected text into the row.

Press the Enter key to put your cursor on the next row.  You can skip a row by pressing the Enter key without typing anything.

When you've made all the corrections, left-click on the Save Corrections button.

## Explanation

When I create a Swing GUI, I use the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern.  This pattern allows me to separate my concerns and focus on one part of the GUI at a time.

Using Java Swing, the MVC pattern is implemented this way:

1. The view reads information from the model.
2. The view does not update the model.
3. The controller updates the model and repaints / revalidates the view.

There's usually not one controller class to "rule them all".  Each `ActionListener` acts as an independent controller.

For this project, I created two model classes, a view class, a `JTable` cell renderer class, and one controller class.

### Model

I created two model classes.  The `ImageText` class holds an OCR image, the OCR text, and the corrected text.  This keeps the corrections separate and allows easier verification of the correctness of the code.

The `ImageTextModel` class holds a `java.util.List` of `ImageText` instances.  Since you didn't provide any OCR image examples, I created some from the text.  This is where you would read the OCR images and the OCR text and put the values into the `List`.

### View

I started the Swing application with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that all Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I created one `JFrame` and two `JPanels`.  The `JFrame` methods must be executed in a specific order.  This is the order I use for all my Swing applications.

The upper `JPanel` holds the `JTable`.  The lower `JPanel` holds the `JButton`.  The `ImageCellRenderer` class allows me to display the `BufferedImage` in the `JTable`.

I use [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to create the `JPanels` and pack the `JFrame`.  This allows the layout managers to place the Swing components and make the `JFrame` as small as possible.

### Controller

The `ButtonListener` class prints the corrected text.  Here's where you would write the corrected OCR text to your file system.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class ImageTextGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ImageTextGUI());
    }
    
    private final OCRTableModel tableModel;
    
    private final ImageTextModel model;
    
    public ImageTextGUI() {
        this.tableModel = new OCRTableModel();
        this.model = new ImageTextModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image Text GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createJTablePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createJTablePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        tableModel.addColumn("OCR Image");
        tableModel.addColumn("OCR Text");
        tableModel.addColumn("Corrected Text");
        
        for (ImageText imageText : model.getImages()) {
            Object[] object = new Object[3];
            object[0] = imageText.getImage();
            object[1] = imageText.getOcrText();
            object[2] = imageText.getCorrectedText();
            tableModel.addRow(object);
        }
        
        JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(220);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(200);
        
        table.setDefaultRenderer(BufferedImage.class, new ImageRenderer());
        table.setRowHeight(40);
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(670, panel.getPreferredSize().height));
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Save Corrections");
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        panel.add(button);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public class OCRTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex < 3) {
                return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
            } else {
                return JButton.class;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return (columnIndex == 2);
        }
        
    }
    
    public class ImageRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, 
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int column) {
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon((BufferedImage) value));
            panel.add(label);
            return panel;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            model.saveImages(tableModel);
        }
        
    }
    
    public class ImageTextModel {
        
        private final List<ImageText> images;
        
        public ImageTextModel() {
            this.images = new ArrayList<>();
            
            // This is where you would read the OCR images and OCR text from your
            // file system and add the information to the List. I generated OCR images to
            // make the GUI look more realistic.
            
            String name = "John Smith";
            images.add(new ImageText(createBufferedImage(name), name));
            name = "George Washington";
            images.add(new ImageText(createBufferedImage(name), name));
            name = "John Adams";
            images.add(new ImageText(createBufferedImage(name), name));
            name = "Thomas Jefferson";
            images.add(new ImageText(createBufferedImage(name), name));
        }
        
        private BufferedImage createBufferedImage(String text) {
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(200, 30, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            
            int pointSize = 20;
            Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, pointSize);
            FontMetrics fm;
            Rectangle2D r;
            
            do {
                g2d.setFont(font);
                fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
                r = fm.getStringBounds(text, g2d);
                pointSize -= 2;
                font = font.deriveFont((float) pointSize);
            } while (image.getWidth() < r.getWidth());
            
            int x = (image.getWidth() - (int) r.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (image.getHeight() - (int) r.getHeight()) / 2 + fm.getAscent();
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
            
            g2d.dispose();
            
            return image;
        }
        
        public void saveImages(OCRTableModel tableModel) {
            for (int row = 0; row < tableModel.getRowCount(); row++) {
                String correctedText = (String) tableModel.getValueAt(row, 2);
                System.out.println(correctedText);
                
                // Here's where you would write the corrected text to a file
                if (!correctedText.isBlank()) {
                    images.get(row).setCorrectedText(correctedText);
                }
            }
        }

        public List<ImageText> getImages() {
            return images;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class ImageText {
        
        private final BufferedImage image;
        
        private final String ocrText;
        private String correctedText;

        public ImageText(BufferedImage image, String ocrText) {
            this.image = image;
            this.ocrText = ocrText;
            this.correctedText = "";
        }

        public String getCorrectedText() {
            return correctedText;
        }

        public void setCorrectedText(String correctedText) {
            this.correctedText = correctedText;
        }

        public String getOcrText() {
            return ocrText;
        }

        public BufferedImage getImage() {
            return image;
        }
        
    }

}
```