# Java Swing GridLayout Change Grid Sizes

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I'm trying to create a program that lists movies in a Netflix style to learn Front-End coding.

How I want it to look in the end:

[image: Example Image How it should look]

My guess is that every movie is a button component with an image a name label and a release year label.

I'm struggling to recreate this look. This is how it looks when I try it:

[image: How it looks when I try it]

The navigationbar in my image is at the page start of a border layout. Below the navigationbar the movie container is in the center of the border layout.

My idea was creating a GridLayout and then create a button for each movie and adding it to the GridLayout.

You can recreate this with this code:

```
public class Main {
private static JFrame frame;

public static void main(String[] args) throws HeadlessException {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setBackground(new Color(32, 32, 32));
    
    JPanel navigationPanel = createNavigationBar();
    frame.add(navigationPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    
    JPanel moviePanel = createMoviePanel();
    frame.add(moviePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Example App");
    frame.pack();
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static JPanel createMoviePanel() {
    JPanel moviePanel = new JPanel();
    
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(0, 10);
    layout.setHgap(3);
    layout.setVgap(3);
    moviePanel.setLayout(layout);
    moviePanel.setBackground(new Color(32, 32, 32));
    
    ArrayList<String> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // Add stuff to the example list
    for(int i = 0; i < 120; i++) {
        exampleList.add(Integer.toString(i));
    }
    
    final File root = new File("");
    
    for(final String movie : exampleList) {
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel();
        
        try {
            File imageFile = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "\\src\\images\\" + "imageName.jpg"); // Try to find the cover image
            
            if(imageFile.exists()) {
                BufferedImage movieCover = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
                picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(movieCover));
            } else {
                BufferedImage movieCover = ImageIO.read(new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "\\src\\images\\temp.jpg")); // Get a temp image
                picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(movieCover));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JLabel movieName = new JLabel("New Movie");
        movieName.setForeground(Color.WHITE);;
        
        JButton movieButton = new JButton();
        movieButton.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        //movieButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        //movieButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        //movieButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        
        movieButton.add(picLabel);
        movieButton.add(movieName);
        
        moviePanel.add(movieButton);
    }
    
    return moviePanel;
}

public static JPanel createNavigationBar() {
    JPanel navBar = new JPanel();
    navBar.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 30, 20));
    navBar.setBackground(new Color(25, 25, 25));
    
    JButton homeButton = new JButton("Home");
    homeButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    homeButton.setBorderPainted(false);
    homeButton.setFocusPainted(false);
    
    JButton movieButton = new JButton("Movies");
    movieButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    movieButton.setBorderPainted(false);
    movieButton.setFocusPainted(false);
    
    // Add all the buttons to the navbar
    navBar.add(homeButton);
    navBar.add(movieButton);
    
    return navBar;
}
}
```

I noticed that the `GridLayout` always tries to fit everything onto the window.

Comment: I'm not sure you really want to do that with a `JButton` (or abuse a `JButton` that way).  A better way would be to use a `JList` wrapped in a `JScrollPane`

Comment: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796471/how-to-change-description-image-in-jlist-java/23797943#23797943) is probably a little more complicated then you need, but the basic idea is what you're trying to achieve (without making `JList` editable)

Comment: `public class Main {` Class (method & attribute names) should be descriptive and clear (unless for e.g. it's a local variable where the meaning should be clear from the context - like a loop counter). If not for your sake a month later when you are wondering what the `Main` class does, then at least for the benefit of others who start out not having the first clue, and the name clashing with all the other unimaginatively named classes in their package dedicated to code testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that's needed is a properly configured `JButton` in a `GridLayout`.

E.G.

[image]

```
public static JPanel createMoviePanel() {
    JPanel movieLibraryPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 10, 3, 3));
    movieLibraryPanel.setBackground(new Color(132, 132, 132));

    int m = 5;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(9 * m, 16 * m, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int ii = 1; ii < 21; ii++) {
        JButton picButton = new JButton("Mov " + ii, new ImageIcon(image));
        picButton.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
        picButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        picButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        picButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        picButton.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.BOTTOM);
        movieLibraryPanel.add(picButton);
    }

    return movieLibraryPanel;
}
```

Here is a complete source for the above with a tweak to put the year on a new line. It uses HTML in the `JButton` to break the button text into two lines.

The input focus is on the first button, whereas the mouse hovers over the '2009' movie:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MovieGrid {

    MovieGrid() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Movie Grid");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.add(createMoviePanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static JPanel createMoviePanel() {
        JPanel movieLibraryPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 10, 3, 3));
        movieLibraryPanel.setBackground(new Color(132, 132, 132));

        int m = 5;
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
                9 * m, 16 * m, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        for (int ii = 2001; ii < 2021; ii++) {
            JButton picButton = new JButton(
                    "<html>Movie<br>" + ii, new ImageIcon(image));
            picButton.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
            picButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            picButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            picButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
            picButton.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.BOTTOM);
            movieLibraryPanel.add(picButton);
        }

        return movieLibraryPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MovieGrid();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same idea's from Andrew Thompson answer but with some minor text alignment changes and hover effect

```
final class Testing 
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  JFrame frame=new JFrame("NEFLIX");
  
  frame.setContentPane(new GridDisplay()); 
  frame.pack();
  frame.setResizable(false);
  
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }
 
 private static final class GridDisplay extends JPanel implements ActionListener
 {
  private GridDisplay()
  {
   super(new GridLayout(0,5,20,20));
   
   setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,255));
   
   BufferedImage image=new BufferedImage(150,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 
   Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();  
   g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);  
   g2d.fillRect(0,0,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight());
   
   HoverPainter painter=new HoverPainter();  
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
    TVShowCard card=new TVShowCard(image,"Show "+i,"199"+i);   
    card.addMouseListener(painter);   
    add(card);
   }
  }

  //highlight only on hover
  private final class HoverPainter extends MouseAdapter
  {
   @Override
   public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    ((TVShowCard)e.getSource()).setBorderPainted(false);
   }

   @Override
   public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    ((TVShowCard)e.getSource()).setBorderPainted(true);
   }  
  } 
  
  private final class TVShowCard extends JButton
  {
   private TVShowCard(BufferedImage preview,String name,String year)
   {
    super();
       
    setContentAreaFilled(false);
    setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    setFocusPainted(false);  
    setBorderPainted(false);

    //I didn't use image icon & text horizontal alignment because the text always horizontally centered aligned but from the expected output it was left  so created 2 labels for the job            

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    addIcon(preview);  
    addLabel(name,year);
      
    addActionListener(GridDisplay.this);
   }
   
   private void addIcon(BufferedImage preview)
   {
    JLabel icon=new JLabel();   
    icon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(preview));  
    add(icon,new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,1,1.0f,0.0f,GridBagConstraints.WEST,GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
   }
   
   private void addLabel(String name,String year)
   {
    JLabel label=new JLabel("<html><body>"+name+"<br>"+year+"</body></html>");   
    label.setForeground(Color.white);  
    label.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    add(label,new GridBagConstraints(0,1,1,1,1.0f,1.0f,GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST,GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,0,0,0),0,0));
   }
  } 
  
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
   TVShowCard card=(TVShowCard)e.getSource();
   
   //do stuff with it
  }
 } 
}
```

[image]

Comment: *"and hover effect"* There are a number of ways to indicate hover built into a standard `JButton`. The border can change, or the focused icon can be swapped for a 2nd that is slightly different. Here is an [example of changing the icon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556). In that screenshot, the mouse is hovering over the ▶ button.

Comment: See the edit to my answer starting with *"Here is a complete source for the above with a tweak.."* to see how to get two-line text in a single `JButton`. Using custom painting here is overkill. A standard button can do all the heavy lifting needed.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson all your points are correct . I was just trying to show all the options available[not optimal but options none the less]