# JList and ListCellEditor?

Tags: java, swing

I have a Swing application that shows a list of complex objects to the user. These are nicely rendered using a ListCellRender, which fills a JPanel with more UI controls. Obviously editing does not work and the components are not enabled to accept input.

Now I want the user to be able to edit the entries. Basically you could think of in-place editing. I tried to simply enable the panel that renders the list entries - but it does not work. What else could/should I do to have an editable list?

Comment: A JList does not support editing and was not designed to display multiple columns of data. Maybe try a `JTable` which allows editing on individual columns. See: [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). If you need to be able to edit the text of a simple JList then check out [List Editor](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/19/list-editor/) for a limited implementation.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796471/how-to-change-description-image-in-jlist-java/23797943#23797943) is why we would recommend a `JTable` over trying to make `JList` editable

Answer (score 0):

So basically the answer is to favour JTable over JList. For anyone questioning that, the JTable can be configured to show one column only, and the difference would not be visible to the user.

Programming wise JTable is more complex and thus justifies that JList is used in simple cases (only one columne, no editing required).