# How to Override File Renaming Event Trigger in JList of JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlist, jfilechooser

I'm working with a JList inside a JFileChooser and I'm trying to achieve a specific behavior related to file renaming. In JFileChooser, files displayed in the JList start the renaming process after a single click on the file, followed by a click on a free area, and then another click on the file. This renaming mode is triggered from a handler in the nested class FilePane.

Here's an overview of the situation:

The renaming mode in JFileChooser's JList is triggered by actions in a handler class.
In contrast, JTable handles similar actions using an event timer, with the actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) method directly tied to cell editing, which is likely triggered by an event generated by one of the timers.
I'm looking for a way to override the default behavior in JList to replicate the single-click renaming feature, similar to what happens in JTable. Below is a snippet from swing current handler class that implements MouseListener:

```
private class Handler implements MouseListener {
    private MouseListener doubleClickListener;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        JComponent source = (JComponent)evt.getSource();
        int index;
        // Handling for JList and JTable with conversion between the two
        // [Code omitted for brevity]
        
        if (index >= 0 && SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(evt)) {
            JFileChooser fc = getFileChooser();
            if (evt.getClickCount() == 1 && source instanceof JList) {
                // Conditions to initiate file renaming
                // [Code omitted for brevity]
            } else if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
                // Handle double-click events
                resetEditIndex();
            }
        }
    }
    // Additional methods omitted for brevity
}
```

My goal is to customize the event that initiates the renaming of files in JList to mimic the one-click approach found in JFileChooser, but I'm struggling to find the right way to do it. How can I modify or override the event handling in JList to allow for single-click file renaming, similar to the behavior in JFileChooser? Are there specific listener or timer configurations that I should consider?

Comment: `JList` itself doesn't have "editable" functionality, so in order to do what you seem to be wanting to, you'd need to roll your own implementation [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796471/how-to-change-description-image-in-jlist-java/23797943#23797943) (which isn't even a fully complete solution).  I'm also not sure what you mean by *"JTable handles similar actions using an event timer"* - cell editing is handled by a `MouseListener` and key bindings

Comment: *How can I modify or override the event handling in JList to allow for single-click file renaming, similar to the behavior in JFileChooser?* - The JFileChooser doesn't support single-click file renaming. First you click on the item to select it. Then you click again to place it in edit mode. Is this the behaviour you are trying to replicate. Or, you mentioned JTable, which does allow you to invoke `setClickCountToStart(1) on the editor to place the cell in edit mode when you click on a new cell. Is this the behavour you are trying to replicate?

Comment: One option is to use a [java.awt.FileDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/FileDialog.html), which will give you a native file chooser with native behavior.  In Windows, that renaming capability will still be present, but it will act just like it does in all other applications’ file choosers.  The disadvantage is that it’s less customizable than a JFileChooser.